# How do I load external HTML content to be manipulated by this JS code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Through the help of another user I have the following JSFiddle that looks at a table and cuts out columns I don't need.

http://jsfiddle.net/9qme9/

What I would like to do is load the HTML (which is actually an aspx file) from an external file instead of manipulating the HTML on the same page  - as is the case of the above link.

I am doing this offline/client-side so PHP is out of the question and the aspx file is not in the same location as *my* page.

I'm a beginner so a JSFiddle example would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Please tudy up your code before posting... Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/9qme9/1/

Comment: @BramVanroy Thanks for reading, but the reason I have arranged it as my link in the Question is because that HTML part of the fiddle is exactly what I would get from the aspx file. Perhaps I should have made that clear in the Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following, which incorporates the previous answer for filtering out the columns you don't want, before appending the filtered-table to the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //define which column headers to keep
    $("#gvRealtime")
        .load("http://fiddle.jshell.net/UqZjt/show/", function(response, status, xhr){
            var html = $(response),
                table = html.find('#gvRealtime'),
                headersToKeep = ['---', 'C6', 'C7', 'C13', 'C14'],
                colsToKeep = [],
                ths = table.find('th');

            $.each(headersToKeep, function(i, v) {
                //finds each header and adds its index to the colsToKeep
                colsToKeep.push(ths.filter(function() {
                    return $(this).text() == v;
                }).index());
            });

            //makes a new jQuery object containing only the headers/cells not present in the colsToKeep
            $('th, td', '#gvRealtime, #gvTotal').filter(function() {
                return $.inArray($(this).index(), colsToKeep) == -1;
            }).hide(); //and hides them
        });

});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9qme9/6/).

Comment: This is great thank you. I have copied this to a local file, however it doesn't appear to work offline - would you happen to know why this is? Is it because the source HTML has to be in the same directory??? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably because of JavaScript's [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), implemented to stop scripts on one website calling scripts on another website, to protect against malicious scripts. If both pages are in the same directory on your localhost then they should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've heard of this before - I'm afraid having them in the same directory is not possible. Any thoughts/workarounds?

Comment: They have to be on the same host, so long as they're on the same server, Localhost or not, they should work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
 $("#elem").load("url.aspx");
```

where #elem is the id of the HTML element where you want to put the content of the external url

check this for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9qme9/5/

Comment: Thanks for the response, would it be possible for you to put this into a new JSFiddle using the source HTML from http://fiddle.jshell.net/UqZjt/show/